# Select columns in a table so that the rows of the new table contain at least one occurence of the initial row elements in R

Tags: python, r, select, unique, dynamic-programming

In fact the question is more complicated : the following dataset has n columns and p rows.

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5... Cn
R1  2   8   5   2   7
R2  2   5   8   7   7
R3  2   5   8   7   7
...
Rp
```

My question is : how can I choose a combination of columns to make a new table in which each row contains each distinct value of the initial rows at least once with the smallest number of non-unique values ?

Example1 : If my table had only the columns C1 to C3 and the rows R1 to R3 selecting C1, C2, C3 is the solution : each row of the new table will contain 2,5 and 8 exactly once.

Example2 : Now if the table ranges from C1 to C5 and R1 to R3, I will select C1,C2,C3 and C5 (not C4).

My first (naive) try was a recursive algorithm in Python :

1. Select a column (Ci)
2. look for another column (Cj) that adds new values in the rows of the resulting table without creating duplicate values,
3. otherwise choose another Cj
4. If no Cj could satisfy the criteria go back to 1

First objection : this approach is clearly suboptimal and the full table has 11 rows and approx 2500 columns

Second objection : If the solution with zero duplicate values does not exists, the algorithm will not give me the second best one.

I suspect there is some kind of dynamic programming hiding behind this problem but I'd much rather use an existing package :)

Comment: This sounds like the vertex cover problem.

Comment: What is the maximum value of any element? If it is low , you can try bitmask+ DP for each row and take a union of the columns got individually O(2^Digits * Rows * Column )